# Casting a generic type into a interface when invoking a method

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to cast `T` in the line `new ConsumeA1<T> ();` to `A1`?
With the current code I'm getting the error:

> Type 'T' cannot be used as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ConsumeA1'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'A1'

```
class Consume<T> where T : A
{
    public Consume()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(A1))
        {
            new ConsumeA1<T> ();
        }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
        {
            new ConsumeA<T>();

        }

    }
}

class ConsumeA<T> where T : A
{

}

class ConsumeA1<T> where T : A1
{

}

interface A
{
}

interface A1 : A
{
}

class Imp1 : A
{

}

class Imp2 : A1
{

}

// ....
class ImpN : A
{

}
```

Comment: you already check that `T` is `A1` so you can simple do `new ConsumeA1<A1> ();`

Comment: What type you are trying to specify as generic parameter to ComsumeA1 ? If it is not an implementation of A1 interface, unfortunately there is no way because not every A is an A1

Comment: @OguzOzgul, before creating, OP already check that `typeof(T) == typeof(A1)`

Comment: ConsumeA1 will work only with generic parameter Imp2 according to the code above

Comment: Yes but generics are not dynamic in that sense. The compiler only knows T as an implementation of A

Comment: Runtime type does not matter

Comment: Therefore, reflection is the way I can think of right now. You can create an instance of ConsumeA1 with typeof(T) with reflection

Comment: I can to instantiate the `class class Consume<T>` with one of the classes `Imp`. I don't want to check of the type of all classes because there are going to be a lot of them.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here but could you try to explain briefly what are you actually trying to do (and for what situation)?
Because maybe it's just ok for you to implement the interface in a generic manner?

Answer (score 0):

There is not point in using generics if you want to cast to a concrete type...
From what I understand all your concrete types contain a Consume() functionality
You can move this method to be part of your A interface.
Then,you don't need a Consume< T> class.
You can just use a method that accepts a A as a parameter and calls Consume()

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        A obj = new Imp1();
        Consume(obj);

        obj = new Imp2();
        Consume(obj);

        obj = new ImpN();
        Consume(obj);

        Console.ReadLine();
      }

      static void Consume(A a)  { a.Consume();  }
  }

  interface A { void Consume(); }

  interface A1 : A { }

  class Imp1 : A  { public void Consume(){ Console.WriteLine("Imp1"); } }

  class Imp2 : A1 { public void Consume(){ Console.WriteLine("Imp2"); } }

  class ImpN : A  { public void Consume(){ Console.WriteLine("ImpN"); } }
 }
```

Now if you need something similar to your sample code you can use generic constraints

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Consume<Imp1>.ConsumeObject();
        Consume<Imp2>.ConsumeObject();
        Consume<ImpN>.ConsumeObject();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  class Consume<T> where T : A, new()
  {
    static public void ConsumeObject()
    {
        new T();
    }
  }

  class ConsumeA<T> where T : A { }

  class ConsumeA1<T> where T : A1 { }

  interface A { }

  interface A1 : A { }

  class Imp1 : A  {   public Imp1() { Console.WriteLine("Imp1"); }      }

  class Imp2 : A1 {   public Imp2() { Console.WriteLine("Imp2"); }      }

  class ImpN : A  {   public ImpN() { Console.WriteLine("ImpN"); }      }
}
```

or with fewer lines of code

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Consume<Imp1>();
        new Consume<Imp2>();
        new Consume<ImpN>();
    }
  }

  class Consume<T> where T : A, new() { public Consume() { new T(); } }

  interface A { }

  interface A1 : A { }

  class Imp1 : A { public Imp1() { System.Console.WriteLine("Imp1"); } }

  class Imp2 : A1 { public Imp2() { System.Console.WriteLine("Imp2"); } }

  class ImpN : A { public ImpN() { System.Console.WriteLine("ImpN"); } }
}
```

or without the Consume< T >class

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Consume<Imp1>();
        Consume<Imp2>();
        Consume<ImpN>();
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void Consume<T>() where T : A, new() { new T(); }
  }

  interface A { }

  interface A1 : A { }

  class Imp1 : A { public Imp1() { System.Console.WriteLine("Imp1"); } }

  class Imp2 : A1 { public Imp2() { System.Console.WriteLine("Imp2"); } }

  class ImpN : A { public ImpN() { System.Console.WriteLine("ImpN"); } }
}
```